# NiftyNet: How to load own data?

Tags: niftynet

I spend some time read doc, but still don't understand:
1. how to load my own data
2. how the image - label are mapped
3. whether exist standard data format

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:
There are a couple ways to load your own data currently by modifying the config files. You can specify your images in a CSV file, by using a configuration section that looks like this:

```
[labels]
csv_file=labels.csv
spatial_window_size = (20, 42, 42)
interp_order = 0
pixdim=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
axcodes=(A, R, S)
```

The csv_file parameter will make NiftyNet use images listed in labels.csv, which should have the format:

```
subject_id1,path_to_label_image_1
subject_id2,path_to_label_image_2
...
subject_idn,path_to_label_image_n
```

The other parameters are described [here](http://niftynet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_spec.html?highlight=axcodes#input-data-source-section).

The other way is to use use the automatic path searching, which looks like this:

```
[modality1]
path_to_search = ./example_volumes/monomodal_parcellation
filename_contains = _T2,patient
filename_not_contains = _T2W
spatial_window_size = (20, 42, 42)
interp_order = 3
pixdim=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
axcodes=(A, R, S)
```

This says look in the ./example_volumes/monomodal_parcellation folder for all files that have '_T2' and 'img' in the file name (excluding files that have '_T2W' in the file name). The subject_id for those images will be the file name with 'img' and '_T2' removed.

Question 2: 
The images and labels are matched up by having the same subject_id. If you have a simple file naming scheme, you can often get away with using the automated search to automatically make the files and subject_ids match. (e.g. patient001_T2.nii and patient001_label.nii would be easily matched by having 'filename_contains = _T2,patient' for the image and 'filename_contains = _label,patient' for the label). Otherwise you can specify the matching explicitly in the CSV files.

Question 3:
NiftyNet support image formats that are handled by nibabel, or if you have installed SimpleITK, by SimpleITK.